# Angular JS - Cannot read local JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

Before my query worked in a sample 1 page(index.html) project but this time , i am working on a project which have tabs(i created project by Ionic Lap with tabs). And i need to print output of JSON file in tab-home.html page. Which not in same local of JS and index.html.

Tab pages are in /Template folder (tabs.html,tab-home.html,tab-account.html)
JS are in /JS folder (app.js,controllers.js,services.js and employees.json)

Here is my codes

in controllers.js

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, webtest) {
    webtest.fetch().then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    })
})
```

in services.js

```
.factory('webtest', function($q, $timeout, $http) {
    var Webtest = {
        fetch: function(callback) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                return $http.get('employees.json').then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }, 30);
        }
   };

   return Webtest;
});
```

in tab-home.html

```
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in data">

    <h2>{{item.product_name}}</h2>   
</ion-item>
```

I didn't touch app.js and index.html. They have default codes.

Thanks everyone,
Mehmet.

Comment: see actual error in browser console.

Comment: Please, paste there log from console with error.

Comment: I see http://localhost:8101/employees.json 404 (Not Found) error in console but this error removed when i updated   this part like $http.get('js/employees.json').then(function(response)  (used js/employees.json instead of employees.json). Even it didn't return any error now , i don't see data.

Comment: Can you put it in a pluker? So it is easy to help you. One thing, you are returning the "then()" function not the promisse when you call "webtest.fetch()". You should return only "return $http.get('employees.json')" and then use the "then()" to handle the http response in your HomeCtrl controller.

Comment: Here two thgins to tries : init $scope.data = [];If it's not that try put your data in a object like $scope.context = {data:[]}; .... $scope.context.data = data;

Comment: after edited json path like js/employees.json it worked fine , but need to stop serve and re-run server

Answer (score 2):

your response should be like {"data": {....

if no :

```
 return $http.get('employees.json').then(function(response) {
                return response;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this directly off your hard drive?  Like the url in the address bar is file://yadda-yadda-yadda?  If so, ajax doesn't work on local files.  You need to run off a webserver.  WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is a project to quickly set up a local web server on windows if that is your operating system.

Comment: no , i serve it by Ionic lap or serve it by cmd (ionic serve android)